# Scoping with pre-made namespace (C++)

Tags: c++, namespaces, include, scope

To avoid scoping everything from the STL, you can type

```
using namespace std;
```

To avoid scoping only a few things, you can type:

```
using std::cout;  
using std::cin;
```

---

I want to write a library that acts the same way.  However, instead of being able to include specific classes, I want to be able to include specific collections of functions.

So, for example, I code:

- A collection of string functions
- A collection of math functions

They are part of the same namespace, but I can include the chunks I want

---

This is sudo-ish code, but I think it gets my idea across:

```
namespace Everything{
    namespace StringFunctions{
        void str1(string & str);
        void str2(string & str);
        void str3(string & str);
        void str4(string & str);
        void str5(string & str);
    }

    namespace MathFunctions {
        void math1(int & num);
        void math2(int & num);
        void math3(int & num);
        void math4(int & num);
        void math5(int & num);
    }
}
```

then I want to be able to do something like:

```
#include "Everything.h"
using Everything::Stringfunctions;

int main(){

    str1("string"); //this works, I can call this!
    math1(111);     //compile error: I've never heard of that function!

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this does not work, and I am kind of confused on how to divide up my library. I don't want to make them classes and then have to use the "dot operator" everywhere, but I also don't want to include a ton of header files.

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way.  I hope everyone can help me take the right approach here.

---

#### EDIT:

It works by writing:

```
using namespace Everything::Stringfunctions;
```

This is very obvious now in hindsight.

Comment: You didn't put `namespace` after your `using`.

Comment: +1 For asking a good question 'goodly'.

Comment: @stonybrooknick You should wait for the question asker to fix their own code; perhaps they didn't realize they were making the mistake. (Unlikely, but nevertheless, it's better to just ask them to fix their code themselves.)

Comment: @muntoo yeah true your right , i edited your code to add a missing namespace as dreamlax also mentioned in your everything.h file

Comment: @stonybrooknick It isn't *my* code. :) (Or are you being sarcastic...?) EDIT: And in this case, it really was the problem! Weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that you have written your library in the example that you gave is sufficient.

People can get every function from the namespace `Everything::Stringfunctions` by using the directive `using namespace Everything::Stringfunctions`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider splitting functionality into different headers regardless, otherwise you'll wind up with nightmare compilation times. That said I think `using namespace Everything::Stringfunctions;` ought to do it (with the extra `namespace` in there. I didn't try compiling though).

Comment: oh definitely! just wrote it that way for clarity

Answer (score 0):

What you want seems to work, provided you use `using namespace` rather than just `using`. See [here](http://codepad.org/KxYyo2zm) (program compiles and outputs '5').